# Why subscribeOn deadlocks if request done from separate thread

Tags: project-reactor, reactive-streams

In the [subscribeOn](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) documentation, its says

```
Note that if you are using an eager or blocking create(Consumer, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy) as the source, it can lead to deadlocks due to requests piling up behind the emitter. In such case, you should call subscribeOn(scheduler, false) instead.
```

Tho some details are given, I'm not quite sure why requests gets piled behind emitter. Can someone explain this please